# ViewController() is called first than appDelegate()?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

In my application , in the appDelegate file , i register fur push notifications take the token and also get the device UDID. I save these variables as global variables.

The next thing i do , is in my viewController connect to a URL using these 2 variables.

However , when from my viewController i call the variables they are (null).

So i thought maybe i was doing something wrong with them. But even when i nslog something on appdelegate() and viewcontroller() , it nslogs first from the viewcontroller...

How is this possible , as what i new is that appdelegate runs first , and secondly how will i be able to use the token and udid variables that i get on the appdelegate , in the viewcontroller?

My code looks like this:

In appdelegate.h just before the `@interface` :

```
extern NSString *newDeviceToken;
extern NSString *udid;
```

In appdelegate.m before the `@implementation` :

```
NSString *newDeviceToken;
NSString *udid;
```

An in my view controller i simply import the delegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: post your applicationDidFinshLaunch code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

where you should get your variables, is run asynchronously.
And yes, it might get called after your RootViewController has been initialized.

You shouldn't perform the URL connection on your ViewController, as you might not yet have an access token.
You should perform this on the delegate method it self.

Now if you want to use a function of your ViewController and don't want to do the server communication in the AppDelegate, get a reference to your ViewController in your AppDelegate, make the URL function on your ViewController public, and call it.

As for getting a reference to your ViewController, this will be hard to answer, without knowing your App's design.

Assuming your App's RootViewController is a NavigationController and let's say the NavigationController RootViewController is named HomeNewViewController, this is how you would get a pointer reference to it from the App Delegate:

```
NavigationController *navigationController = (NavigationController*) [self.window rootViewController];

HomeNewViewController *homeController = (HomeNewViewController*)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then let's say in the HomeNewViewController, you have a function called uploadToken.

You could then do:
`[homeController uploadToken];`

and upload it.

Comment: Thank you Leftos.I am looking on it now. Χρόνια πολλά.

Comment: What do u mean exactly get a reference to your view controller in your appdelegate and then call the public function? Could you give an example?

Comment: I have edited my answer, but this makes assumptions about your App's design.

Answer (score 1):

`application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is not called immediately after  calling `[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:]`.

That means you can expect to be having the token at the time your views are being loaded. Separate your UI from the connection code. Your connection must be triggered when `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called, not at some point of your view controller life cycle. Note that there can be also a dialog asking user for approval before `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called.

Comment: fair enough but why i dont even see the device udid? i simply get it like this : NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]; This should be called immediately right?

Comment: `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` was deprecated in iOS 5. Don't expect it to return you some data any more.

Comment: it does return me some data...in the appdelegate though.

Comment: @donparalias This is pretty hard to answer without seeing the problematic code. However, your application would be rejected by app store if it used `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]`.

Comment: We have already 2 apps on the store using it. Also deprecated means that it could stop working some time soon. Not that it doesnt work right? Cause my apps run well on ios6 too. Finally how can apple know that i am using this method anyway?

Comment: @donparalias Apple does API verification when you are uploading your app (e.g. you can't use undocumented APIs). Regarding rejection - http://www.theverge.com/2012/3/25/2900787/apple-rejects-UDID-apps. My bad thinking `uniqueIdentifier` would return `nil`. That's not true. You have to add more code to your question if you want a good answer. Variable declarations are not enough.

Comment: [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier] is not an undocumented API. Yes, Apple has deprecated it and will in short time, reject Apps using it, but it's not an undocumented API nor will it not return anything.

Comment: @Lefteris I never said it's undocumented and I already said it was my mistake thinking it will return `nil`. Apple rejects applications using it for a year already.

Comment: @Sulthan No Apple is not rejecting applications using it. They will start rejecting them on May 1st. https://developer.apple.com/news/ Please stick to official announcements.